# Linux Mint: root running bitcoind on startup?

Tags: bitcoind, linux

Every time I start my machine, root user tries to run bitcoind. I've checked .profile and such, but there don't seem to be any answers there. what else could be making my computer try to run the daemon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options where this could be loaded on startup, check the root crontab file (crontab -e) also look for files in the /etc/init.d/ folder it could be included in rc.local or another startup script.